# Address of location in letter

Tags: grammar, forms-of-address

I want to give the reference of a famous shop in my shop's address but that's situated on the 3rd floor and my shop at the 2nd floor (above the ground floor).

**How can I write my address?**

• *The Bunnies Shop downstairs Shamlians Academy*

• *The Bunnies Shop down floor Shamlians Academy*

If my my both the addresses are not correct please suggest me the correct one.

Thanks.

Comment: I think "Second floor (below Shamlians Academy)" would be the most idiomatic.

Comment: You can also use “downstairs from”. Some real examples might help: “The new restaurant Lesa is upstairs from the popular wine bar Embla.”, “The JB-HiFi store in the city is downstairs from Harris Scarf on Collins Street.”, “Find us downstairs from the Dome Cafe.”, “Our store is located on the 2nd floor, downstairs from Woolworths.”

Comment: I  think you are right but my doubt is there about the preposition you used "downstairs from" I think there's no need to use "from".

Comment: Kausar - Definitely include the "from." (When I read your question, the first thing I thought was, "There needs to be a _from_ after the word _downstairs_." It sounds very odd without it.)

Comment: Thank you for your assistant.